# C# OpenXML Determine if paragraph is hidden text

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to figure out how to determine if a paragraph has hidden text or not. It is easy to do through interop, but I can't seem to figure it out in openxml. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
MainDocumentPart mdp = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;
XDocument xDoc = mdp.GetXDocument();
IEnumerable<XElement> = xDoc.Descendants(W.p);

foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs)
{
    // I want to check if this paragraph has hidden text or not, if it does I want to skip over it.
    // if (paragraph.hasHiddenText()) { continue; }
    // else, get the content
    string paraText = paragraph.Descendants(W.t).Select(t => (String)t).StringConcatenate();

}
```

Comment: Did you try creating a document with some hidden text then unzipping the file and looking at how it was generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep using the open xml sdk instead of linq-to-xml it's way easier:

```
MainDocumentPart mdp = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

foreach(var paragraph in mdp.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>())
{
    ...
    string paraText = paragraph.Descendants<Run>()
                               .Where(r => r.RunProperties.Vanish != null)
                               .Aggregate("", (text,r) => text += r.InnerText);
}
```

While the sdk might be slightly slower, it's way more convenient to use. Unless you're processing hundreds of documents a minute, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: thank you. The reason I was using the linq was because someone provided a solution to determining the list item value using it. I was able to just search the first node value to find the vanish code.